# Run command when two elements have same distance to window top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, offset

I want to do something when two elements have the same distance to the browsers top.

I've tried this:

```
var scrollTop      =   $(window).scrollTop(),
     _menuOffset    =   $('#2').offset().top,
     _aboutOffset   =   $('#1').offset().top;

distance1      = (_menuOffset - scrollTop);
distance2      = (_aboutOffset - scrollTop);

if (distance1 == distance2 ) {
    alert('test');
}​
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rxs2m/135/

Hope someone can help.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Your $('#1') don't match your element IDs. The other thing is to wrap your script in a function named scrollTest or something and set $(document.body).on('scroll', scrollTest); so you can capture scroll events. When I troubleshoot code like this, I always do a console.log(distance1,distance2). Other than that your logic looks about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Rxs2m/135/

The IDs are incorrect, so `.offset()` returns nothing (and `.offset().top` causes an error).

Change to `$("#en")` and `$("#to")`.

Finally, wrap everything in a callback to `$(window).scroll()` and it is checked each time the window scrolls.

Comment: Thanks!

Like this:

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop      =   $(window).scrollTop(),
         _menuOffset    =   $('#menudock').offset().top,
         _aboutOffset   =   $('#aboutus').offset().top;
         
    var distance1      = (_menuOffset - scrollTop);
    var distance2      = (_aboutOffset - scrollTop);
    
    if (distance1 == distance2 ) {
        alert('test');
    }
});